# Are there any functions of collecting Lums when doing race challenges?

Tags: rayman-legends

I just bought Rayman Legends on Steam and since then, has only played for only 2 days. On the first day, I reached Awesomeness Level 1, in which I could start participating in daily challenges.

The first daily challenge I participated was to reach a certain distance as quick as possible. Now, inside that stage, there are Lums all over the place, in which sometimes you need to do specific maneuver to get them, like jumping on the platform and gliding (e.g. hair helicopter for Rayman).

At first, I tried to get most of them, thinking that it might give some speed boost to the character (I got bronze time when doing that). But after experimenting with the controller for a while, I found out that I can travel faster with dash + attack, but for doing that, I have to be on the ground for most of the time (well, *it might not be the best way*, but I tried not to read guides/hints/tips until I'm desperate for it). So, I tried this while ignoring the Lums, and I could get silver time instead!

So, my question is, are there any functions of collecting Lums when doing race challenges? Or is it just for unlocking purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just helps to earn the *Sooo rich!* achievement/trophy:

> Gather 1 million lums and unlock the final Hero

Personally, I tend to ignore the lums during the challenges, and just focus on going fast, going far, or whatever the challenge requires. Of course, the lums sometimes will give you hint on the path you should take.